# I want to create a route to automatically redirect users to the home page upon logging in

Tags: angularjs, node.js

The below code describe my app.js file.

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies'])
    .config(config)
    .run(run);

config.$inject = ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider'];
function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            controller: 'HomeController',
            templateUrl: 'home/home.view.html',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })

        .when('/users/login', {
            controller: 'LoginController',
            templateUrl: 'login/login.view.html',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })

        .when('/register', {
            controller: 'RegisterController',
            templateUrl: 'register/register.view.html',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })


        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/users/login' });
}

})();
```

The one below describe my login controller.js file: I wrote this route for logging in registered users to the database and creating tokens once the username and password are correct. What I want now is to create an auto route that will redirect the users to the home page once the password and username is correct.

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app')
    .service('Users1', function($http) {
        this.logUser = function(user) {
            return $http.post("/users/login", user).
                then(function(response) {
                    return response;
                }, function(response) {
                    alert("Error logging in user.");
                });
        }
    })
    // .controller('RegisterController', RegisterController);
    .controller("LoginController", function($scope, $location, Users1) {
        $scope.back = function() {
            $location.path("/users/login");
        }

        $scope.login = function(user) {
            Users1.logUser(user).then(function(doc) {
                var userUrl = "/" + doc.data.id;
                $location.path(userUrl);
            }, function(response) {
                alert(response);
            });
        }
    })
})();
```

Below is the html file for the login controller file:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
<h2>Login</h2>
<form name="form" role="form">
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.username.$dirty && form.username.$error.required }">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" ng-model="user.username" required />
        <span ng-show="form.username.$dirty && form.username.$error.required" class="help-block">Username is required</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.password.$dirty && form.password.$error.required }">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" ng-model="user.password" required />
        <span ng-show="form.password.$dirty && form.password.$error.required" class="help-block">Password is required</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$invalid || vm.dataLoading" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="login(user)">Login</button>

        <a href="#/register" class="btn btn-link">Register</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.login = function(user) {
        Users1.logUser(user).then(function(
            $location.path("/");
        }, function(response) {
            alert(response);
        });
    }
```

If you just want to redirect user to the home page. and if you want the userid as urlParams then you should go with this

```
.when('/:id', {
        controller: 'HomeController',
        templateUrl: 'home/home.view.html',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    })
```

and the controller

```
$scope.login = function(user) {
        Users1.logUser(user).then(function(doc) {
            var userUrl = "/" + doc.data.id;
            $location.path(userUrl);
        }, function(response) {
            alert(response);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use run method to redirect user to home on landing. 
You can check when even ever there is route change and redirect him to right place.

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
  //add your logic here. if user next contains next route. 
});
```